# using Get-ADUsers to find info in powershell not working, term not recognized

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to retrieve few info from my AD users, with the following command on PowerShell:

```
get-aduser -identity username -Properties * | select DisplayName, City, State
```

But it gives me this error:

```
get-aduser : The term 'get-aduser' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-aduser -identity username -Properties * | select DisplayName, Cit ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (get-aduser:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I also tried adding this import:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
```

But I instead get this other error:

```
Import-Module : The specified module 'ActiveDirectory' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module ActiveDirectory
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (ActiveDirectory:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to install the module first. Read about [Remote Server Administration Tools (RSAT) for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/system-management-components/remote-server-administration-tools)

Comment: As aside, don't ask for **all** properties with `-Properties *` if you only want three of them. Change that to `-Properties DisplayName, City, State`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install [RSAT Tools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520) in order to use the `ActiveDirectory` module.

If you have `Windows 10 October 2018 Update` or later installed, you can install RSAT Tools as a Windows Feature:

> **Note:** The sample below doesn't use the direct name since there is a version suffix at the end of the name.

```
Get-WindowsCapability -Online | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "Rsat.ActiveDirectory.DS-LDS.Tools*" } | Add-WindowsCapability -Online
```

Otherwise, you can install RSAT Tools from the link I provided earlier. Directions are included there for how to install manually for still-supported versions of Windows.